# IOS - What is the ObjC NSObject equivalent of Swift Character type?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsstring, character

I've been meaning to constrain input to one character only, and instead of using `String` and checking for length, I decided to go with `Character`.

The problem is that I can put it in an `NSArray`, but the type becomes a `_SwiftValue`, so I don't know how to use that in ObjC code.

Answer (score 2):

In Objective-C it is char, which is a primitive and just contains a byte. So char* is an array of characters, which is essentially a string.

I would stick to NSString and check for the length if I was you.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I'm pretty sure `NSArray` does not take primitive types. Since `NSArray` does hold the Swift `Character` as `_SwiftValue`, it means there is an equivalent NSObject type.

Comment: You are correct, it does not take primitive types, I was referring to char*. That is why I suggested to use NSString so you can use NSArray to contain them.

Comment: Understood. I would use `NSString` if there were no other options, but it seems like there might be. Of course, if it's not a public type and yada yada, I would have to settle with `NSString`.

Comment: Well there is another option, and that is a char array. If you are really worried about memory usage then I would do this, but NSString is the better option.

Comment: @BridgeTheGap `_SwiftValue` is a value box when there _isn't_ an equivalent Objective-C type to bridge to (otherwise it would bridge). You get a `_SwiftValue` any time you try to use a non-`@objc` type from Swift in Objective-C (which is why there's no good way to use it in Objective-C; it's opaque). You will have to use a different type to represent it; one additional option is to store it inside of an `NSValue` or an `NSNumber`, instead of a string.